# Copying Unique values realtime

Tags: excel, duplicates, unique-values

[image]I have a spreadsheet with all invoices which include vendor number, around 9000 rows. Most of those invoices are for a handful of vendors.
I want to get the vendors exist in the column and copy them in another sheet, but in real time. As I am trying to make an automated sheet, so no need to advance filter them every time.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Use Pivot tables

Comment: Pivot tables worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using no filtering and exclusion of duplicates in Data menu by dedicating 2 service columns(SC):
say you have your vendor names stored in column 5 and first SC in column 4 while second in column 3
1) first SC formula **"=iferror(if(countif(RC5;RC5:R1C5)>1;0;row());"")"**
2) second SC formula **"=iferror(rank(RC4;C4;1);"")"**
say you need your list of unique vendors in th same sheet... then you get a numbered list from 1 to number of supposed vendors + several.
3) a column next to this list contains formula "=vlookup(RC[-1];C3:C5:;3;false)"
in the end you have an online list of unique vendor names

Comment: I am really sorry, it seems I am not bright as I should be. Cause I am a bit lost. I will try to attache a screenshot showing what I want to do, and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Filter Views (Difference Between Filters vs FilterViews)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Also Check [here (Filter Views in Google Sheets)](https://sites.google.com/a/york.ac.uk/workingwithdata/google-sheets/filter-views)

Comment: Unfortunatly, the filtring works on the same sheet, I wanted to copy the date to another sheet and sum the values of each duplicated raw. You can do that by consilidate or advance filtring. But both doesnt give a real time update when the data in the original sheet is changed